Как параметризировать тип данных TypeScript передаваемый в просы компонента react?
Мне нужно описать тип входящих пропсов для компонента Radio. Компонент реализует паттерн рендер пропс и получает: пропс render, который содержит компонент который нужно отрендерить; и пропс data, который содержит объект пропсов, которые нужно передать в render. При этом в data может приходить любой объект, но в render должна приходить функция которая на входе получает такой же тип данных как у data, а на выходе возвращает jsx. Т.е. если в data тип T, то тогда в render должно приходить (props: Т) => JSX.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как описать тип такого компонента через джинерики ts, и как потом вызывать этот компонент?

Вообще проблему не вижу... Вот ровно как ты сказал - так и напиши - дженерик T у пропсов и компонента.

interface Props<D> {
  data: D;
  renderSomething: (data: D) => React.ReactNode;
}

function Abobus<T>({ data, renderSomething }: Props<T>) {
  return <div>{renderSomething(data)}</div>;
}

<Abobus <number> data={5} renderSomething={d => <span>{d}</span>} />


А нельзя описать так, что бы, не нужно было указывать   и ts сам бы выводил, что рас в data передано number, значит T тоже number?

да. в данном примере Вы можете вовсе не указывать дженерик <number>, TS и без него увидит какой тип данных будет передаваться в props-ы и неявно присвоит этот тип дженерику D в интерфейсе Props. но в этом теряется суть строгой типизации, для чего сам TS и создан. типизируйте всё, что только можно, и будете в безопасности

@Август в безопасности не будете с TS. Он никогда не создавался для обеспечения типобезопасности приложения и не может его строго обеспечить. Разве что в связке с очень строгим ts-lint и то, есть вопросы. Но да, это гораздо безопаснее чистого JS.
